# Make 2 classes share the same instance of an object in Java

Tags: java, swing, object, jframe, instance

I was wondering if anyone could help me. I am stuck with something that seems simple. Say I initialize a Student object with the values of name, age and address in one class. How can I share THAT INSTANCE with another class, eg enable methods in the second class to make changes to the instance, thereby affecting the first class etc.

I was thinking of using JFrames where a new frame would popup and a button would affect values on the first frame.

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice) for some reasons why you shouldn't avoid multiple frames...

Answer (score 1):

mutators can help you there. or, the singleton pattern, if you want to go "hard-knox".
it's a pattern that allows only one single instance of a class in a jvm to exist.

just look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Comment: interesting nick name

Comment: indeed, same as on Daniweb :)

Answer (score 1):

in java if you pass reference of an object to a method and do any changes to that object property, it will change the actual object properties(call by reference)

also if you want to have only single object of a class that needs to be shared across other classes create a [singleton pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html)